# assign contact object in who field of task

Tags: apex, contact, tasks

I dont have contact id ,only have contact object.
Can i assign contact object in who field of task and later i insert contact then put id in task's whoid?

For eg:

```
    con = new Contact(Lastname = 'Candidate manage brokerage Contact');
    contactList.add(con);

    taskObj = new Task(subject = 'Portal Contact Setup');
    **taskObj.who = con;**
    taskObj.whatid = coustomObject.id;
    taskList.add(taskObj);
```

Comment: You can insert parent and child records together with the help of External Id. Check this [blog](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.in/2012/03/create-parent-and-child-records-in-one.html).

Comment: Are you inserting that contact in same transaction or just initialized a contact?

Answer (score 0):

step1:
first you have to insert contact

step2: 
you have to pass that contact id to whoId field

You cant Insert how the way you have inserted in code.

I can see few mistakes in your code.You have to instantiate task object like this:

```
      task  t= new Task();
```

and task object you have to refers contactId as

```
   "whoid"
```

Please check below code:

```
  contact con= new Contact(Lastname = 'Candidate manage brokerage Contact');
 insert con;
 task  t= new Task(subject = 'Portal Contact Setup');
 t.whoId =con.Id;
 insert t;
```

If you are inserting list of contact object.You have to go for for loop

I have considered task subject will be same for List of contacts

```
List<contact> conlist=new List<contact>();
   for(integer i=0;i<=5;i++){
    contact con= new Contact(Lastname= 'Candidate manage brokerage Contact1'+i);
  conlist.add(con);}

insert conlist;
List<task> tasklist=new List<task>();
    for(contact con:conlist){
system.debug('##############'+con.Id);
task  t= new Task(subject = 'Portal Contact Setup1');
   t.whoId =con.Id;
  tasklist.add(t);
 }
 insert tasklist;
```